# Generating initial velocity field

Tags: fourier-transform, fftw

I am trying to generate initial velocity field which satisfies incompressible flows condition. To formulate this I am using Rogallo's procedure formulation which is given by 
$$
\tilde{u}(k) = \frac{\alpha k k_2 + \beta k_1 k_3}{k \sqrt {k_1^2 + k_2^2}} \hat{k_1} + \frac{\beta k_2 k_3 - \alpha k_1 k}{k \sqrt {k_1^2 + k_2^2}}\hat{k_2} - \frac{\beta \sqrt {k_1^2 + k_2^2}}{k}\hat{k_3}
$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are given by 
$$
\alpha = \sqrt{\frac{E_0(k)}{4\pi k^2}} e^{i \theta_1} \cos \phi,\hspace{0.5cm} \beta = \sqrt{\frac{E_0(k)}{4\pi k^2}} e^{i \theta_1} \sin \phi 
$$
in which $E_0(k)$ is the assumed energy spectrum in my case its 
$$
E_0(k) = A k^4 e^{-0.14 k^2}, \hspace{1cm} k \in [k_a,k_b]
$$
My doubt is what are the terms $k , k_1,k_2,k_3$ in this formulation?
Secondly, after substituting these terms and obtaining the velocities in fourier space what is the procedure to enforce conjugate symmetry so that real velocities are obtained in the physical space for simulation?

Answer (score 1):

The method produces a velocity field in Fourier space, where $k_1,k_2,k_3$ are the components of the wave vector $k \in {\mathbb R}^3$. In order to get a velocity field in physical space, you need to do an inverse Fourier transform. This typically done via the inverse Fast Fourier Transform (iFFT).

Comment: Thank you Wolfgang for the reply. My doubt is if I apply inverse Fast Fourier Transform (iFFT) for the values obtained from this procedure I am ending up with complex numbers again in the real space instead of real values? Is there anything which I need to do before applying iFFT?

Comment: I think you ought to be able to just take the real part, but must admit that I don't know for sure.

Comment: I don't think we can just neglect imaginary parts with this we will loose crucial information in the complex space which might induce more errors. Anyways thank you :)

Comment: The question to answer is whether $\text{Re}(iFFT(\tilde u(k)))$ has the same power spectrum as $iFFT(\tilde u(k))$. I don't know the answer to this question, though.

Answer (score 0):

FFTW has real-to-complex, real-to-real, and complex-to-real plans. For example, in 1d to take a complex fft result and get a real data result you call the function "fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d" where the *c2r* means complex-to-real.

In 3d the function is "fftw_plan_dft_c2r_3d" which does the same thing I describe above but in 3D.

Check out the documentation [here](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Multi_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html#Multi_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data)